# Como escribir en un fichero txt utilizando escuchadores

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, interfaz

Hola he creado una interfaz gráfica para crear usuarios y añadirlos a un txt. Introduzco todos los datos en la ventana crear estudiante, pero al pulsar en guardar no escribe el nuevo usuario en el txt.

Tengo creada las siguientes clases:
Ventana en la que he creado la interfaz gráfica, aquí podemos ver, crear, eliminar o salir.
Al pulsar en crear, se abre una nueva ventana para rellenar los datos personales del usuario. En la parte inferior se encuentra un botón para guardar. El problema es que no se almacena la información en el txt.

**Boton guardar**

```
public class botonGuardarEstudianteActionListener implements ActionListener {

private Ventana ventana;
private String rutaFichero = "\\C:\\gestion\\datos.txt";

public botonGuardarEstudianteActionListener() {
    this.ventana = ventana;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String nombre= new String(); 
    String apellidos= new String(); 
    String email= new String(); 
    Sexo sexo= Sexo.HOMBRE;  
    EstadoCivil estadoCivil = EstadoCivil.SOLTERO;
    Calendar fechaNacimiento= new GregorianCalendar();;     

    String listEstudiantes; 

    String dd, mm, aa;
    dd = mm = aa = "" ;             

    listEstudiantes = "No hay estudiantes creados";  

    nombre = VentanaCrearEstudiante.getNombre();
    apellidos = VentanaCrearEstudiante.getApellidos();
    email = VentanaCrearEstudiante.getEmail();         

    if(nombre.length() == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ventana,
                "Debe Ingresar un Inmueble",
                "Error Ingreso Datos", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);        
    }
    else {

        if(VentanaCrearEstudiante.getSexo().equals("Hombre")) {
            sexo= Sexo.HOMBRE;
        }
        else {
            sexo= Sexo.MUJER;
        }

        if(VentanaCrearEstudiante.getEstadoCivil().equals("Soltero")) {
            estadoCivil = EstadoCivil.SOLTERO;
        }
        else if (VentanaCrearEstudiante.getEstadoCivil().equals("Casado")) {
            estadoCivil = EstadoCivil.CASADO;
        }
        else if (VentanaCrearEstudiante.getEstadoCivil().equals("Divorciado")) {
            estadoCivil = EstadoCivil.DIVORCIADO;
        }
        else {
            estadoCivil = EstadoCivil.VIUDO;
        }

        int control = 1;         

        if(control == 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ventana,
                    listEstudiantes,  "Informacion", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);                  
        }
        else {
            try {   
                Estudiante nuevoEstudiante = new Estudiante(control, nombre, apellidos, email, sexo, estadoCivil, fechaNacimiento);
                control = 1;
                int identificador;
                boolean existe = false;
                do {
                    identificador = getIdentificador();
                    for(Estudiante inmueb : ventana.listEstudiantes) {
                        if(inmueb.getIdentificador() == identificador) {
                            existe = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!existe) {
                        nuevoEstudiante.setIdentificador(identificador);
                        control = 0;
                    }
                }
                while(control == 1);

                ventana.escribirDatosDeSalida(String.format(nuevoEstudiante.toString()));  
                ventana.listEstudiantes.add(nuevoEstudiante);

            } catch(Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: "+ex);   
            }
        } 
    }       
}
private int getIdentificador()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(1000);
}
private void guardarEnFichero() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File fichero = new File(this.rutaFichero);
    FileOutputStream outFichero = new FileOutputStream(fichero);
    OutputStreamWriter escritor = new OutputStreamWriter(outFichero);
    for (Estudiante estudiante : listEstudiantes) {
        escritor.write(estudiante.lineaCsv() + "\n");
    }
    escritor.close();
}
```

}

**Boton crear estudiante**

```
public class botonCrearEstudianteActionListener implements ActionListener {


private Ventana ventana;

  public botonCrearEstudianteActionListener(Ventana ventana) {
        this.ventana = ventana;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String listEstudiantes;
        
        ventana.activarListadoEstudiantes();
    }
    
}
```

**Ventana crear y anadir**

```
public class VentanaCrearEstudiante extends JFrame implements ActionListener {   
private JLabel labelSubtitulo, labelNombre, labelApellidos, labelEmail;
private static JLabel labelSexo;
private static JLabel labelEstadoCivil;
private static JLabel lblFormatoFecha;
private static JTextField txtNombre;
private static JTextField txtApellidos;
private static JTextField txtEmail;
private JTextField txtFecha;
private JButton btnGuardar,btnCancelar;
private Choice chEstadoCivil;
private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

public VentanaCrearEstudiante(){
    String listaEstudiantes = "";
    componentes();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400,450); 
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);      
    setResizable(false); 
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("Crear y anadir");   
}

public void componentes(){
   
    labelSubtitulo = new JLabel();
    labelSubtitulo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    labelSubtitulo.setBounds(92, 20, 260, 20);
    labelSubtitulo.setText("Rellene todos los recuadros");
    getContentPane().add(labelSubtitulo);
    labelNombre = new JLabel(); 
    labelNombre.setBounds(20, 50, 150,20);
    labelNombre.setText("Nombre");
    getContentPane().add(labelNombre);       
    txtNombre = new JTextField(); 
    txtNombre.setBounds(165, 50, 215, 20);
    getContentPane().add(txtNombre);       
    labelApellidos = new JLabel();
    labelApellidos.setBounds(20, 80, 150, 20);
    labelApellidos.setText("Apellidos");
    getContentPane().add(labelApellidos);       
    txtApellidos = new  JTextField();
    txtApellidos.setBounds(165, 80, 215, 20);
    getContentPane().add(txtApellidos);        
    labelEmail = new JLabel();
    labelEmail.setBounds(20, 110, 110, 20);
    labelEmail.setText("Correo electronico");
    getContentPane().add(labelEmail);       
    txtEmail = new  JTextField();
    txtEmail.setBounds(165, 110, 215, 20);
    getContentPane().add(txtEmail);        
    labelSexo = new JLabel();
    labelSexo.setBounds(20, 140, 50, 20);
    labelSexo.setText("Sexo");
    getContentPane().add(labelSexo);        
    JRadioButton rdbtnHombre = new JRadioButton("Hombre");
    buttonGroup.add(rdbtnHombre);
    rdbtnHombre.setBounds(165, 139, 80, 25);
    getContentPane().add(rdbtnHombre);        
    JRadioButton rdbtnMujer = new JRadioButton("Mujer");
    buttonGroup.add(rdbtnMujer);
    rdbtnMujer.setBounds(249, 140, 69, 25);
    getContentPane().add(rdbtnMujer);       
    labelEstadoCivil = new JLabel();
    labelEstadoCivil.setBounds(20, 170, 80, 20);
    labelEstadoCivil.setText("Estado Civil");
    getContentPane().add(labelEstadoCivil);     
    chEstadoCivil  = new Choice();
    chEstadoCivil.setBounds(165, 168, 110, 20);
    chEstadoCivil.add("Soltero");
    chEstadoCivil.add("Casado");
    chEstadoCivil.add("Divorciado");
    chEstadoCivil.add("Viudo");
    getContentPane().add(chEstadoCivil);        
    JLabel fechaNacimiento = new JLabel("Fecha de nacimiento");
    fechaNacimiento.setBounds(20, 203, 128, 16);
    getContentPane().add(fechaNacimiento);        
    txtFecha = new JTextField();
    txtFecha.setBounds(165, 203, 110, 22);
    getContentPane().add(txtFecha);
    txtFecha.setColumns(10);                
    lblFormatoFecha = new JLabel("[formato DD/MM/YYYY]");
    lblFormatoFecha.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblFormatoFecha.setBounds(20, 219, 138, 16);
    getContentPane().add(lblFormatoFecha);
   
    btnGuardar = new JButton();
    btnGuardar.setBounds(100, 350, 100, 20);
    btnGuardar.setText("Guardar");
    btnGuardar.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(btnGuardar);
    btnCancelar = new JButton();
    btnCancelar.setBounds(220, 350, 100, 20);
    btnCancelar.setText("Cancelar");
    btnCancelar.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(btnCancelar);   
}

private void registrarEscuchadores() {
    btnGuardar.addActionListener(new botonGuardarEstudianteActionListener());
    }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {       
    if(e.getSource().equals(btnGuardar)){ 
        this.dispose();
        Estudiante estudiante = null;
        Ventana.listEstudiantes.add(estudiante);
        }
   
}
public static String getNombre() {  
    return txtNombre.getText();
}

public static String getApellidos() {
    return txtApellidos.getText();
}

public static String getEmail() {
    return txtEmail.getText();
}

public static String getSexo() {
    return labelSexo.getText();
}

public static String getEstadoCivil() {
    return labelEstadoCivil.getText();
}

public static String getFechaNacimiento() {
    return lblFormatoFecha.getText();
}
```

}

**Clase ventana**

```
public class Ventana extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final String TITULO = "gestion usuarios";
private String rutaFichero = "\\C:\\gestion\\datos.txt";
public static ArrayList<Estudiante> listEstudiantes = new ArrayList<Estudiante>();
FileInputStream fis = null;
ObjectInputStream ois = null;

private JLabel labelSubtitulo;
private JButton btnVer, btnCrear, btnEliminar, btnSalir;
private JPanel panelInicio, panelBotones, panelTextoSalida;
private JScrollPane panelScrollSalida;
private static JTextArea cajaTextoSalida;

public Ventana() {
    setTitle(TITULO);
    inicializarComponentes();
    registrarEscuchadores();
    pack();
    setVisible(true);        
    String listaEstudiantes = "";
    
    try {
        recuperarDeFichero();
        Ventana.escribirDatosDeSalida(String.format(+ listEstudiantes.size() + " estudiantes disponibles\n"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("El fichero no existe");
    }
    escribirDatosDeSalida(String.format(listaEstudiantes)); 
}
  
private void inicializarComponentes() {

    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0)); 
    JLabel panelInicio=new JLabel("Gestion");
    panelInicio.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    panelInicio.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    panelInicio.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 20));
    panelInicio.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panelBotones = new JPanel();
    btnVer = new JButton("Ver");
    panelBotones.add(btnVer);
    btnCrear = new JButton("Crear y anadir");
    btnCrear.addActionListener(this);
    panelBotones.add(btnCrear);     
    btnEliminar = new JButton("Eliminar");
    panelBotones.add(btnEliminar);
    btnSalir = new JButton("Salir");
    panelBotones.add(btnSalir);     
    panelTextoSalida = new JPanel();
    panelTextoSalida.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0)); 
    panelScrollSalida = new JScrollPane();
    panelTextoSalida.add(panelScrollSalida);
    cajaTextoSalida = new JTextArea(5, 0);
    cajaTextoSalida.setEditable(false);
    panelScrollSalida.setViewportView(cajaTextoSalida);
    getContentPane().add(panelInicio);
    getContentPane().add(panelBotones);
    getContentPane().add(panelTextoSalida);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 550));      
}   
    
private void registrarEscuchadores() {
    btnVer.addActionListener(new botonVerEstudiantesActionListener(this));
    btnCrear.addActionListener(new botonCrearEstudianteActionListener(this));
    btnEliminar.addActionListener(new botonEliminarEstudianteActionListener());
    btnSalir.addActionListener(new botonSalirActionListener());
}

private void recuperarDeFichero() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(rutaFichero));

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String lineaCsv = sc.nextLine();
        if (lineaCsv != null && lineaCsv.length() > 0) {
            listEstudiantes.add(new Estudiante(lineaCsv));
        }
    }
}

private void guardarEnFichero() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File fichero = new File(this.rutaFichero);
    FileOutputStream outFichero = new FileOutputStream(fichero);
    OutputStreamWriter escritor = new OutputStreamWriter(outFichero);
    for (Estudiante estudiante : listEstudiantes) {
        escritor.write(estudiante.lineaCsv() + "\n");
    }
    escritor.close();
}
        
    public static void escribirDatosDeSalida(String texto) {
        String formato = "hh:mm:ss a";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formato);
        String tiempo = dateFormat.format(new GregorianCalendar().getTime());
        cajaTextoSalida.append(tiempo + " :: " + texto + "\n");
    }
     
    public void activarListadoEstudiantes() {     
        this.panelInicio.setVisible(true);
    }
     
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource().equals(btnCrear)){ 
        this.dispose();           
        new VentanaCrearEstudiante();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Saludos. Le falto agregar el código o la estructura donde esta fallando el proceso; también el error (en caso de existir alguno). Por lo menos el código de la estructura de la que solicita apoyo.

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero no me deja enviar el código.

Comment: Escribe el código, no metas una captura de pantalla salvo para mostrar lo que pasa con la GUI. Mira [mcve]. En todo caso hay que aprender a diferenciar las cuestiones, una es ejecutar un código usando listeners, y otra es escribir un código que escriba en fichero.... ¿con cuál de las dos tienes problemas?

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, pero me deja muy pocos caracteres.

Comment: Ahora creo que si...

Comment: No comprendo, veo dos métodos "guardarFichero" definidos, pero no invocas ninguno de los dos desde ningún sitio. En todo caso lo primero que deberías saber si el método se está invocando o no (pon un System.out.println para ver si se imprime algo por consola)

Comment: Pues supongo que ahí debe estar el error...soy muy nuevo en Java.

Comment: Voy revisando el código, leyendo en el foro, y cada vez que toco algo se estropea otra cosa...

Comment: Realmente, si no sabes como invocar a un método creo que deberías empezar con unos ejercicios más sencillos. Programas de consola, modo texto, sin GUI.

Comment: Pues tienes razón, pero si hay que hacerlo...

Comment: La verdad es que agradecería si alguien me dijese como poder resolver el problema